# I Am creating the java api to conncet kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am writing the java api to create `kafka` producer 
I have an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.(Ljava/util/Properties;)V
>     at in.co.hadooptutorials.data.generator.cdr.kafka.main(kafka.java:65)

Below is my code

```
public class kafka {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 String TOPIC_NAME = "test";
    String objec ="hello";

    Properties props=new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap-server", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
    System.out.println("confing work.");
    KafkaProducer<String,String> sampleProducer= new KafkaProducer<String,String>(props);

    ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(TOPIC_NAME,objec);        
    sampleProducer.send(record);

    sampleProducer.close();
    System.out.println("SimpleProducer Completed.");

}
}
```

How to slove this problem?

Comment: Do you have the correct version for all libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `bootstrap.servers` instead of `bootstrap-server`.

Always better to use `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig` while setting the configs. eg:

```
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9090");
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

That *always* means: some class wants to use something from another class, and at runtime, that other thing isn't there.

This has always the same root cause: incompatible code levels. Meaning: you are running libA in version n, and libA uses libB. Now libA needs libB to be version *m*, but because of an inconsistent setup, your libB has a **different** version that isn't compatible to version *m*.

Long story short: look into the way you setup your dependencies. Ensure that they are consistent, and reflect what kafka claims to be supported.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes a call to the constructor of `ProducerConfig`:

```
ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
```

At runtime, you're seeing an error that says that that method does not exist. The constructors defined in versions up to 1.0.2 do not support being passed a `Properties` object. (https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0.2/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerConfig.java#L360-L366).

```
ProducerConfig(Map<?, ?> props) {
    super(CONFIG, props);
}

ProducerConfig(Map<?, ?> props, boolean doLog) {
    super(CONFIG, props, doLog);
}
```

Note that in version 1.1.0, such a constructor was added: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.1.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerConfig.java#L364-L366

```
public ProducerConfig(Properties props) {
    super(CONFIG, props);
}
```

The fact that your code compiles says that a suitable library version can be found *at compile time*.  However, at runtime, no such suitable version can be found (meaning at runtime you're likely linking to an older version that does not support this method).

The solution will be to check what versions of Kafka's libraries you are including, both at compile time and runtime, which will vary according to how you build your project (e.g. via Maven, Gradle etc).